# How to solve a same site and multiple projects of global.asax file

Tags: c#, global-asax

We have 3 web api projects with different functions，such as: order, coupon, shopping cart, and the 3 projects belong to different developer.

When released, merge to the same iis site, but there can only one Global.asax file：

```
<%@ Application Codebehind="Global.asax.cs" Inherits="Company.Product.Order.MvcApplication" Language="C#" %>
```

the other 2 Global.asax.cs files of code can't to fire, how to solve the problem???

thanks!

Comment: I would recommend using just one project if all the projects indeed are so "connected" that you merge them somehow when released. Three developers working on a single project is not a problem if version control is done properly. Other option is to create three sites in IIS, one for each project.

Comment: @Esko for later distributed deployment, in order to decouple , we divided the three project development, currently being published in a site, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you supposed to run 3 different website in the same web application.
if you want to keep the same domain with different endpoint such as:

```
[domain]/app1   
[domain]/app2
```

you can set a virtual directory for each app under the same web application.

But if you want your 3 projects in the same endpoint i think you should join them into one project.